# UPDATE statment not executing resulting in Primary Key Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following statement that I am running;

```
 declare @prod varchar(25)
    set @prod = (select top 1 prodref
            from dba.proditem
            where prodcateg = '84' 
            AND obsolete = 0
            AND defaultsupersededby is null
            AND charindex('/B/',proddesc) > 0
            AND salesanalysis is null 
            order by prodref asc)
    declare @cnt INT
    set @cnt = 1
    while @cnt <= (select count(prodref)
            from dba.proditem
            where prodcateg = '84' 
            AND obsolete = 0
            AND defaultsupersededby is null
            AND charindex('/B/',proddesc) > 0)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601110GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601115GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601120GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601130GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601140GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601150GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601160GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity, ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601170GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601179GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'601180GST',100,1,3)
      INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks(opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref,
                                    defaultquantity,ratioquantity,linktype)
      VALUES ('C',@prod,'600965GST',100,1,3)
      UPDATE dba.proditem
         SET salesanalysis = 'B'
       WHERE prodref = @prod
      set @cnt = @cnt+1
    END
```

The statement appears to run through once fine, then on the second time it errors telling me the 'Primary Key' in proditemlinks is not unique. The primary key for proditemlinks is 'opco_code','prodref','linked_prodref'.

It works fine on the first run, On the second run the lines are inserted but the update statement at the end is not executed, so it tries to insert the last item again, as it is not filtered out on the select statement.

**What I am trying to achieve**

When certain new products are created into `dba.proditem` I need to create some related items into the `dba.proditemlinks`. My `select` filters out the products that have related items.

As I cannot guarantee only 1 item at a time is created I am using `select top 1` and a loop to go through all the rows and insert the required items.

Enable to ensure I am not duplicating items, I added the `update` statement after the `insert` to ensure the item is filtered out in the starting `select` statement.

Comment: There's almost certainly a much simpler set based way of doing what ever you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the table?

Comment: @MartinSmith there probably is a better way. I just don't know it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @prod VARCHAR(25);

DECLARE @cnt INT;

SET @cnt=1;

WHILE @cnt <=
              (
               SELECT COUNT(prodref)
               FROM dba.proditem
               WHERE prodcateg = '84'
                     AND obsolete = 0
                     AND defaultsupersededby IS NULL
                     AND CHARINDEX('/B/', proddesc) > 0
                     AND salesanalysis IS NULL
              )
BEGIN
SET @prod=
          (
           SELECT TOP 1 prodref
           FROM dba.proditem
           WHERE prodcateg = '84'
                 AND obsolete = 0
                 AND defaultsupersededby IS NULL
                 AND CHARINDEX('/B/', proddesc) > 0
                 AND salesanalysis IS NULL
           ORDER BY prodref ASC
          );
INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks
                             (opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref, defaultquantity, ratioquantity, linktype
                             )
VALUES
       ('C', @prod, '601110GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601115GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601120GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601130GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601140GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601150GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601160GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601170GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601179GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '601180GST', 100, 1, 3
       ),
       ('C', @prod, '600965GST', 100, 1, 3
       );
UPDATE dba.proditem
       SET salesanalysis='B'
WHERE prodref = @prod;
SET @cnt=@cnt + 1;
END;
```

However if you provide a bit more info about what it is you are trying to do we can provide you with a better set based approach.

this is what I assume you want to do in set based approach:

```
    INSERT INTO dba.proditemlinks
                             (opco_code, prodref, linked_prodref, defaultquantity, ratioquantity, linktype
                             )
       SELECT A.opco_code, B.prodref, A.linked_prodref, A.defaultquantity, A.ratioquantity, A.linktype
       FROM
           (
           SELECT 'C' opco_code, NULL prodref, '601110GST' linked_prodref, 100 defaultquantity, 1 ratioquantity, 3 linktype
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601115GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601120GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601130GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601140GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601150GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601160GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601170GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601179GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '601180GST', 100, 1, 3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C', NULL, '600965GST', 100, 1, 3
           ) AS A
       CROSS JOIN
       (
        SELECT prodref
        FROM dba.proditem
        WHERE prodcateg = '84'
              AND obsolete = 0
              AND defaultsupersededby IS NULL
              AND CHARINDEX('/B/', proddesc) > 0
              AND salesanalysis IS NULL
        ORDER BY prodref ASC
       ) AS B;

UPDATE dba.proditem
       SET salesanalysis='B'
WHERE salesanalysis IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have edited my question with what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonathanGriffin based on what you explained my set based  approach should work. I suggest testing it out for yourself before running it on prod ;)

Comment: @JonathanGriffin one note, be careful using CROSS JOIN as they create a Cartesian product of two sets and this could lead to very large datasets. Just something to keep in mind but in this case it should be fine